# How to convert PDFTemplateResponse to bytes-like object in Django?

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use `wkhtmltopdf` to generate a PDF and send it as an attachment via email. Here is my view:

```
class MYPDFView(View):
    template = 'pdftemplate.html'

    def get(self, request):

        data = {}

        response = PDFTemplateResponse(
            request=request,
            template=self.template,
            filename="hello.pdf",
            context= data,
            show_content_in_browser=True,
            cmd_options={'margin-top': 10,
            "zoom":1,
            "viewport-size" :"1366 x 513",
            'javascript-delay':1000,
            'footer-center' :'[page]/[topage]',
            "no-stop-slow-scripts":True},
        )

        email = EmailMessage(
            'Hello',
            'Body goes here',
            'from@example.com',
            ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
            ['bcc@example.com'],
            reply_to=['another@example.com'],
            headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
            attachments=[('demo.pdf', response, 'application/pdf')]
        )

        email.send()

        return response
```

The error I am getting is a `TypeError` and it says `expected bytes-like object, not PDFTemplateResponse`.

I am assuming that my `response` variable, which I am returning to see my PDF is not the type that I am supposed to provide in the `attachments` attribute.

My question is, how can I convert the PDFTemplateResponse to bytes-like object before providing it in `attachments` triple?

Answer (score 1):

```
return_file = "tmp/hello.pdf"    
temp_file = response.render_to_temporary_file("hello.html")
wkhtmltopdf(pages=[temp_file.name], output=return_file)
email.attach_file(return_file)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24289477/)

Comment: How can I save a temp file on my server with `wkhtmltopdf` library? I seem to only be able to save file on the client's side.

Comment: the view runs on the server so file is generated serverside, you can try NamedTemporaryFile if you are using it in production.

Comment: Thanks. `render_to_temporary_file` is a method? It doesn't seem to work in the latest version. `render_content` is available.